# Custom Eloquent relation which sometimes returns $this Model

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relation

I have a Model `Text` which has a 1-to-many-relation called `pretext()`, returning a 1-to-many-Relationshop to `Text`, like so:

```
class Text extends Model
{
    public function pretext(){
       return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Text', 'pretext_id');
    }

   public function derivates(){
      return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Text', 'pretext_id');
   }
}
```

If a `$text` does not have any pretext (which, in my scenario, means `$text['pretext_id'] == 0`) $text->pretext() shall return the `$text` itself. When I try

```
public function pretext(){
   if ( $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Text', 'pretext_id') ) {
       return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Text', 'pretext_id');
   }
   else {
       return $this;
   }
}
```

I get the error

> local.ERROR: LogicException: Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation

when the else-part is executed. So my questions are:

1. How do I turn $this into an object of type Relation? or alternatively:
2. How can I achieve my goal on a different way?

Comment: You can't make `$this` into a Relation. I suggest you check everytime if the `Text` has a `Pretext` or not : `$text->pretext ? "Has pretext" : "No pretext";`.

Comment: Just write your relation function without the `if/else`, then make a separate function that returns either the relation, or itself.  Laravel functionality depends on a relation function returning a relation, so you should just wrap the function separately with your custom logic.

Comment: @Jeff Maybe an accessor is a solution, dunno if it works with relations : https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try dynamic props

```
class Text extends Model
{
    protected $appends = ['content'];
    public function pretext(){
       return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Text', 'pretext_id');
    }

   public function getContentAttribute(){
      $pretext = $this->pretext()->get();
      if ($pretext->count()) {
        return $pretext;
      }
     return $this;
   }
}
```

Then in controller or view if you have the instance
(consider optimizing it if you have N+1 issues)

```
$obj = Text::find(1);
dd($obj->content);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can create another method that calling pretext() and check the returned value.

```
public function getPretext() {
    $value = pretext();
    return ($value)? $value : $this; 
}
```